# PHP SQL UPDATE one field per row in thousands of rows all different each constructed in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a Large_table with fields named 1 (ID)  thru 10 and 10k plus rows.

The Update statement causes things to slow down to a point where some records fail to update at all.

If I run

```
UPDATE Large_table SET SOME_FIELD = '$testdata'
```

it takes <1 sec from the PHP ,so its the WHERE clause that is the issue.

Running

```
UPDATE Large_table SET SOME_FIELD = 'apple' WHERE ID ='1'
```

from the php where it is in the foreach loop and so runs 10k times  >30 sec and time out.

I need to: 
1 fetch all the rows ( could fetch single row if i do a pre select but that seams like doubling up and the fetch appears efficient and quick).
 Fetching all the data as in a lot of rows we need all the data in others there is only some fields, but that changes daily.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Large_table "); $stmt->execute(); // Works quick.

foreach ($stmt as $row){
        echo $row['1'];// works at .8 sec sometimes less
        $testdata = 'apple';

//PHP CONSTRUCT THE OUTPUT Field for each row differently depending upon id and other feilds - so for testing lets call it $testdata = 'apple' and assume it changes as the issue is not in this part

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Large_table SET SOME_FIELD = '$testdata' WHERE ID = '$row['1']' "); $stmt->execute();                

        }
```

I tried the CASE THEN WHEN complied approach but the sql statement becomes horrendous so surly cannot be the best way of doing this.

So What is the quickest most efficient way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the dB table itself had a issue which showed no detectable errors other than this write issue.

so

```
Export table as text (SQL dump)
Drop table
Restore table (with the SQL dump backup)
```

Now the THEN WHEN method is the quickest until the statement length reaches its max.

The next fastest is the bind_param outside of the foreach loop, version as suggest by  Michael ( thanks) which is what is currently working.

Answer (score 0):

Try preparing the update statement and binding the parameters outside the `foreach` and then within the `foreach` set the parameters and execute the statement.

```
$update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Large_table SET SOME_FIELD = ? WHERE ID = ?"); 

$update->bind_param('si', $testdata, $id);

foreach ($stmt as $row)
{

  $id = $row[1];

  $testdata = 'apple'; // I'm guessing in the real code this changes per row?

  $update->execute();        

}
```

If this still takes too long then you can always use [`set_time_limit(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: Hi - Thanks ,  But still Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded .  Also if set $testdata = 'apple --'.$row[1];  only returns one id not changing but if I echo in the same loop $row[1] it changes correctly

Comment: for a test drop out the foreach loop and loads in 0.6 sec as i $update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Large_table SET SOME_FIELD = ? WHERE ID = ?"); 

$update->bind_param('si', $testdata, $id);

//foreach ($stmt as $row)
{

  $id = '111';$row[1];

  $testdata = 'apple'; // I'm guessing in the real code this changes per row?

  $update->execute();        

//}

Comment: You can use `set_time_limit(0)` to prevent that fatal error. I'm not sure how else to speed the script up. I don't know what you mean by saying that it only returns one ID. Are you sure that the ID is the second column in the table (as the first column will be in `$row[0]`)?

Comment: $row[1] when echo in the loop shows each as expected but when applied to the $id = $row[1]; in the loop  the value entered into the database is only the first( but correct) - Just running it with set_time_limit(0) and it looks like its going to take 10 min plus which wont work for us , so re think